# Load Javascript just for admin in silverstripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

Im trying to add some custom javascript to my admin but not having such a good time. What I tried so far is.

```
Requirements::javascript('../mysite/modules/widgets/widgets/calculator/admin/js/admin.js');
```

The path is correct because when I do fopen to that it returns true.

I have also tried the following.

```
LeftAndMain::require_javascript('../mysite/modules/widgets/widgets/calculator/admin/js/admin.js');
```

Same thing with fopen.

It doesn't give any error niether is it loaded(I checked network tab in dev tools)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path should be relative to the site root not the cms or framework folders. In other words: 'mysite/modules/widgets/widgets/calculator/admin/js/admin.js'

Depending on your situation, I've had more luck using yml for this. I'm not convinced the dynamic loading always works perfectly on ajax requests. In this case it would look like:

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_javascript:
    - mysite/modules/widgets/widgets/calculator/admin/js/admin.js
```